# target border style inside css

Tags: css, responsive-design, styling

okay...

I would like to know if it's possible to target a border style that's inside a class.

I would like to do this so that when the browser window gets resized the border gets hidden or  display:none.

sample of my code:

```
<div id="chuck" class="descr-text col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
some content goes here
</div>
```

And my css

```
.descr-text {
display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
border-right.img_beef{
    display:none;
}
}
```

I know I could probably just wrap it in another div and then then target it when the window gets to that size, But I was wondering if there isn't a more clean simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to decipher exactly what you want since your class names don't match up to your markup. But if you want the border to be hidden when it reaches a certain breakpoint:

```
.chuck {
  border: 2px solid #BADA55;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  border: 0;
}
```